# Performance Impacted - Eden space starvation when old gen grows

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

We are using open-jdk 11 and 2GB is used as the max heap size. The application works smoother till it has enough Eden space and performance starts to degrade when the Eden space shrinks to less than 300MB. Whenever the oldgen reaches 1GB (50%), the Eden space is shrunk to less than 50GB.  When the Eden space goes less than 50MB, the JVM hangs. After restarting only, the application is back to its normal state.

Please help me to understand why it is not expanding more than 1GB (50%) since we have 2GB of the max heap size.

Comment: Could you please elaborate `the JVM hangs`?. is there any log, OOM, ... ?

Comment: What is “OpenJDK LL”? And how can the Eden space ever be 50GB, when you have at max 2GB?

Comment: @usuario There is no OOM. Application has a background job, which usually took 30ms to complete a task, but during the issue time, it gradually increases to more than a minute (or minutes) and after some time there is no response (the last job started and was not completed). By the time, we have restarted the application.

Comment: @Holger It is typo, corrected.

Comment: It’s still not clear what this double-lowercase-L is supposed to mean. A Roman two, an obfuscated eleven, or something else.